# Import an operator to be extended in Julia

Tags: module, julia

I was trying to define:

```
.*(s1::String, s2::String) = string(s1,s2)
```

and got an error: `function Base..* must be explicitly imported`, so I did:

```
import Base..*
```

but got another error: `invalid operator "..*"`.

How should I import this operator?

Comment: you can also use `Base.:(.*)(s1::String, s2::String) = string(s1,s2)` without explicitly `import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
import Base.(.*)
```

What is the use case?

Comment: Cool. Not much of a use case here, just trying to follow some examples in a Julia book.

Comment: Note that in Julia 0.6, this is deprecated, since `.*` corresponds to a `broadcast` operation with the `*` operator.

Comment: How do you do elementwise multiplication in 0.6 then?

Comment: @qed: it is still `.*`  but in 0.6 `.<anything>` is kind of automatically defined once you have defined `<anything>`. The `.` functionality for element-wise (Which is was broadcasting does in this case), is now part of the language. And has fusing behaviour for speed and other great things.